# Disable borders in Web Content Display via template

Tags: liferay, velocity

I'm creating a set of custom structures (and matching templates) for Web Content Displays on a Liferay site.

To make things more convenient for site maintainers, I would like one of these templates to suppress look-and-feel borders by default.

I've found documentation and samples online showing how to disable borders for portlets that are embedded in the theme, but I haven't had any luck applying those techniques inside a WCD template.

Here's the code I've seen embedded in a theme:

```
#set ($VOID = $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue("portlet-setup-show-borders", "false"))
#set ($VOID = $theme.runtime("customportletname_WAR_pluginname", "", $velocityPortletPreferences.toString()))
$velocityPortletPreferences.reset()
```

Here is how I've applied it to my template:

```
#set ($VOID = $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue("portlet-setup-show-borders", "false"))
<div class="custom-wcd wcdnormal">
    <h2>$title.getData()</h2>
    $content.getData()
</div>
$velocityPortletPreferences.reset()
```

I'm not surprised that it didn't work -- there's nothing analogous to the $theme.runtime call that applies the prefs to a portlet, but I also don't know whether $theme.runtime is appropriate at this layer, and if it is, what value to supply as the first argument. I suspect this last is the most likely alternative, but I don't know how to identify the WCD portlet to $theme.runtime, nor do I know how to track that information down (I'm not a Java dev by any stretch).

And just to clarify: it is *not* acceptable to [disable borders on all portlets by default](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/portal-predefined-settings), nor am I in a position to modify the Java controller that consumes journal-article components at render-time.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple and direct:

```
$velocityPortletPreferences.setValue("portletSetupShowBorders", "false") 
$velocityPortletPreferences.setValue("languageIds", "pt_BR,en_US")
$velocityPortletPreferences.setValue("displayStyle", "1")
$theme.runtime("82", "", $velocityPortletPreferences.toString())
$velocityPortletPreferences.reset()
```

This example is for embed the language portlet (Portlet ID = 82), direct in one of .vm theme files, in my case this code is on navigation.vm.

Comment: Finally had an opportunity to test this. It works! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

Liferay property/preference names have a tendency to change sometimes. I created a hook this week to create a site, populate it with pages containing portlets and also to provision the CMS with a default set of structures, templates and articles. I too had to turn off the borders for my portlets and needed to set the following preference name to false to achieve that: **portletSetupShowBorders**

I java code it did this as follows:

```
PortletPreferences prefs = PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil.getLayoutPortletSetup(page, portletInstanceId);
prefs.setValue("groupId", String.valueOf(page.getGroupId()));
prefs.setValue("articleId", article.name());
prefs.setValue("portletSetupShowBorders", "false");
prefs.store();
```

From a Liferay Journal Template you should be able to use the following code to turn of the borders of the portlet that will show an article that uses the template:

```
#set ($portletPreferencesService = $serviceLocator.findService('com.liferay.portal.service.PortletPreferencesLocalService'))
#set ($companyId = $getterUtil.getLong($companyId))
#set ($ownerId = 0) ## PortletKeys.PREFS_OWNER_ID_DEFAULT
#set ($ownerType = 3) ## PortletKeys.PREFS_OWNER_TYPE_LAYOUT
#set ($plid = $getterUtil.getLong($request.theme-display.plid))
#set ($portletId = $request.theme-display.portlet-display.id)
#set ($portletPreferences = $portletPreferencesService.getPreferences($companyId, $ownerId, $ownerType, $plid, $portletId))
#set ($VOID = $portletPreferences.setValue('portlet-setup-show-borders', 'false'))
#set ($VOID = $portletPreferences.store())
```

Just remember that you also need to add the following line to your portal-ext.properties:

```
journal.template.velocity.restricted.variables=
```

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful response, but this solution doesn't satisfy my criteria. I'm trying to discover if there is a way to do this via the VM code available inside a custom template, not via java (whether in a controller or custom hook). Still upvoting, in case someone else finds this useful.

Comment: Seems I didn't understand your question fully, but with your additional comment I looked into the problem again and was able to produce some velocity code that removes the borders from the portlet that displays an article based on a template with this code. I hope this fully answers your question.

Comment: Wow. Very thorough response. I don't yet know whether I have the option of tweaking the properties file, so I may not be able to pursue this, but it seems to work on my local workstation. Very nicely done.